# Как поменять ось заркаски. В heatmap plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, графики

Есть heatmap plotly, построенный с помощью примерно вот такого кода:

```
trace.append(
    go.Heatmap(
    z = pivot_df.values,
    y = pivot_df.index,
    x = pivot_df.columns
))
```

Который выводит в итоге вот такой heatmap

[image: Heatmap]

Таким образом получается что закраска идет по оси абсциссы, то есть какое самое больше число в ряду, то и закрашиваем как самое "горячее".

**Вопрос**: есть ли возможность сделать так, что бы закраска была по ординате, то есть самое большое число внутри колонки, закрашивается как самое "горячее"

Comment: Погодите, так закраска не зависит от таких вещей, она в абсолютных величинах идёт по всей таблице сразу. Справа у вас там нарисована шкала раскраски. Цвет ячейки тут зависит только от значения в этой ячейке. Если я правильно вижу шкалу, то жёлтое - там, где значение 50000. И совершенно не важно при этом, какие числа в других ячейках по вертикали и по горизонтали, какие максимумы/минимумы в столбце или в строке. Важно только какие максимумы и минимумы по всей таблице, от этого зависит раскраска. Если у вас разного масштаба величины в разных колонках, тут стандартный `heatmap` не подойдёт.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, спасибо, я тоже об этому подумал. Понял что мне нужно что-то вроде диаграммы Маримекко